# How to remove only strings from an object array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, filter

I'd like to filter my array and delete only strings.
I've tried few things but nothing works. Could anyone help me with this? What is wrong with my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
public class Program
    {
        public static int[] FilterArray(object[] arr)
        {
            ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList(arr);
                        foreach (var ar in myAL) {
                        if (ar is string) {
                            myAL.Remove(ar);
                        }
                }
                    int[] myArray = myAL.Cast<int>().ToArray();
                    return myArray;
        }
    }
```

Best regards

Comment: Do you want to remove strings or return ints as this function seems to suggest?

Comment: Try : if (ar.GetType()  ==  typeof(string)) {

Comment: What do you mean by `nothing works`? Are you getting any error? What sample input you are using and what output you are getting?

Comment: `ar.GetType() != typeof(string)`

Comment: You don't need to remove anything. Just use `OfType<int>()` to retrieve only integers.

Comment: You can´t **modify** a list while **iterating** it.

Comment: This code will only return the integers in the array (Cast<int> will throw on anything else)

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
public static object[] RemoveStrings(object[] arr)
{
    return arr.Where(x => (x is string) == false).ToArray();
}
```

Using `ArrayList` is unnecessary

---

If you want to support all enumerables:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> RemoveStrings(IEnumerable<object> items)
{
    return items.Where(x => (x is string) == false);
}
```

Usage example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> items = new List<object>() {
            "pizza",
            1,
            4,
            10,
            "banana"
        };

        object[] filteredItems = RemoveStrings(items).ToArray();

        foreach(object item in filteredItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object> RemoveStrings(IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        return items.Where(x => (x is string) == false);
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 1
> 4
> 10
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove elements from the `ArrayList` while inside a `foreach` loop. Use a `for` loop instead. Or you could just do this

```
return arr.OfType<int>().ToArray(); //courtesy of @DavidG
```

Or if your goal was to simply remove the string elements from the array, it's much simpler using `List<>`'s `.RemoveAll()` method:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>(arr);
objects.RemoveAll(x => x is string);
```

The modification will be applied to the list though, not the original array.

Comment: Much easier to do `arr.OfType<int>().ToArray()` though.

Comment: Care to explain why only taking `int`s is better than removing `string`s?

Comment: @DavidG that is cleaner indeed

Comment: Of course, it still doesn't deal with my comment on the question. And no need to credit me, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick suggestion for a solution:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace RemoveStringFromArray
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int[] RemoveString(object[] a)
        {
            return (from e in a
                    where !(e is string)
                    select (int) e).ToArray();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] a = new object[5];
            a[0] = "Start";
            a[1] = 1;
            a[2] = "Midle";
            a[3] = 10;
            a[4] = "End";

            foreach (var e in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element {0}", e);
            }

            var i = RemoveString(a);

            Console.WriteLine("After removing strings");

            foreach (var e in i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element {0}", e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This gives the output:

```
Element Start
Element 1
Element Midle
Element 10
Element End
After removing strings
Element 1
Element 10
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove values from the array. Your method seems to return only integers from the original array. Any other type would throw if you use `Cast<int>`, even longs.

This will throw :

```
var arr=new object[]{1,4L};
var result=arr.Cast<int>();
```

The equivalent to your function is a simple call to `OfType<>` instead of `Cast<>`, eg :

```
var intsOnly=arr.OfType<int>().ToArray();
```